# scala sort a set of a certain class

Tags: scala, set, sortedset

I have a set of a certain dto i created.

The dto is named "NumericValue", and has the following class members:
1) time: Long
2) value: Double

I have a set named "points", and i want to sort it according to increasing time, i.e. 0, 1, 2, 4, 100,...

Attached is code:

```
val points: set(NumericValue) = numericValueSet

val setSorted = collection.immutable.SortedSet[Long]() ++ points
```

I did the following:

However the result isn't sorted according to time.

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Result isn't unsorted because there is not `Ordering` for your class.

You can explicit implement `Ordered`:

```
case class NumericValue(time: Long, value: Double) extends Ordered[NumericValue] {
  override def compare(that: NumericValue): Int =
    Ordering[Long].compare(this.time, that.time)
}
```

or create `Ordering` for your set:

```
val set = SortedSet[NumericValue]()(new Ordering[NumericValue]() {
  override def compare(x: NumericValue, y: NumericValue): Int =
    Ordering[Long].compare(x.time, y.time)
})
```

Result should be ordered:

```
set + NumericValue(345, 45) + NumericValue(453, 123) + NumericValue(5, 5)

res0: scala.collection.SortedSet[NumericValue] = TreeSet(NumericValue(5,5.0), NumericValue(345,45.0), NumericValue(453,123.0))
```